# MySQL how to get data from .frm file?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have what I believe is a corrupted MySQL table. In the database I can see there is only a `.frm` file, not a `.mdi` or `.mdy` for it. How can I recover data from this `.frm` file?

I believe that I have to get data from the `ibdata1` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no data in the `.frm` file; that file only contains the table definition.  However, if you're not running a MyISAM table, it's expected that there will be no `.MYD` or `.MYD` files, because those are only used for MyISAM tables.  Instead, the data will be somewhere else -- for InnoDB tables, for instance, it'll be in your `ibdata*` files (or perhaps in a per-table file if you've got `file_per_table` turned on).

Comment: is there a tool i can use to just view data in the ibdata file?

Comment: Most people use MySQL.

Comment: Lol yeh i think i forgotten my password, i give it a go thanks

Comment: That's easy to fix: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442

Answer (score 1):

The .frm file doesn't really contain any data--it's just the table definition.  You can read the specifics [here](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats).

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool [dbsake](https://github.com/abg/dbsake).

1. Download it with `curl -s get.dbsake.net > dbsake`
2. Make it executable `chmod u+x dbsake`
3. Retrive the information from your .frm file `./dbsake frmdump path/to/frm/file.frm` this will output something like:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `mytable`
-- Created with MySQL Version 5.7.28
--

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Option 2**

You also could spin up a mysql sandbox instance by:

```
dbsake sandbox -D mysql-backup-dir/
~/sandboxes/sandbox_20200621_192450/sandbox.sh start
~/sandboxes/sandbox_20200621_192450/sandbox.sh mysql
```